# Quick Start site is not reachable

Tags: installation

I'm trying to launch a [Quick Start](https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_start) distro on macOS with MAMP:

```
[519] : php core/scripts/drupal -vvv --verbose  quick-start

 Select an installation profile [Install with commonly used features pre-configured.]:
  [standard  ] Install with commonly used features pre-configured.
  [minimal   ] Build a custom site without pre-configured functionality. Suitable for advanced users.
  [demo_umami] Install an example site that shows off some of Drupal’s capabilities.
 > demo_umami

Creating file: sites/default/settings.php
18/18 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓]
Congratulations, you installed Drupal!
Username: admin
Password: hIuWCqqnaD-TostT
Drupal development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8888>
This server is not meant for production use.
One time login url: <http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/reset/1/1560664888/oDldybNCOH_0nRc1n4YXZWm2NwEehXnN63rWHq_Isqo/login>
Press Ctrl-C to quit the Drupal development server.
Browser command: open 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/reset/1/1560664888/oDldybNCOH_0nRc1n4YXZWm2NwEehXnN63rWHq_Isqo/login?destination=%2F'
Server command: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8888' '.ht.router.php'
```

Unfortunately the given URL returns with HTTP error code 500. Also I added `-vvv` and `--verbose` no additional error messages are visible.

When I change from MAMP to OS X standard PHP installation the browser shows:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '.ht.router.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

Actually there's no `.ht.router.php` from where I started the quick-start command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be more of a MAMP issue. Probably same happens when installing a WordPress for example, no?

Comment: Well it also happens without MAMP. What about the missing file?

Comment: Maybe redownload it from somewhere. Does a normal site installation work? Like with adding a host to MAMP and then accessing `hostname/install.php` in your browser?

Comment: I didn't think quick-start worked on anything but native PHP as it was designed to give an evaluator something to spin up a Drupal site within 3 commands using PHP's native web server without requiring a full stack. Additionally the "Quick Start" project is not the same as the "quick-start "command. Are you trying to test one or the other?

Comment: The quick-start core command worked fine for me just now. I made sure I was not running any web server and cleared any existing settings.php file that I had to make sure I was running it cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

Well that was a nasty one. I downloaded and unpacked the latest Drupal version as instructed. But then made a copy using Finder. Unfortunately this leaves out the all files starting with a `.`.

After copying the files on the comannd line everything works as ecpected. Thanks to @leymannx for pushing me into the right direction.